# Selecting a section of data from CSV in d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I created a bar chart by creating a new csv which was part of a bigger dataset. I want to now use the data from the original data set to plot my bar graph by selecting only two columns (Ward and Unemploymet) and one months data. How do I do this?

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unemployment by Ward Bar Chart</title>

<style type="text/css">
  .axis text{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333333;
  text-anchor: end;
}
  .axis path{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#333333 ;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges
  font-family: Arial;
}
.bar{
    stroke: none;
    fill: #012C3B;

}
.textlabel{
    font-family:  Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color: #333333;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>
  var margin = {top:20, right:0, bottom:60, left:60},
width  = 475;
height = 350;
padding = 100;


var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", "30%")
.attr("height", "70%")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height); 

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

 var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.right - margin.left], .1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(yScale)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(function(d) {return d + "%"})


  d3.csv("Unemployment.csv", function(error, data)
 {

 //map function goes through every element, then returns a number for                  Unemployment
 data = data.map(function(d){ 
 d["Unemployment"] = +d["Unemployment"]; 
 return d;
  });

 //yscale's domain is from zero to the maximum "Unemployment"
 yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d["Unemployment"]; })]);

 //xscale is unique values in Ward (Ward, since they are all different)
   xScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d["Ward"]; }));
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d["Ward"]); })
  .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d["Unemployment"]); })
  .attr("height", function(d){ return height - margin.top - margin.bottom -          yScale(d["Unemployment"]); })
  .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale.rangeBand(); })
  .style("font-family", "Arial");


//adding y axis to the chart
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .call(yAxis)
 .style("color", "#333333")
 .style("font-family", "Arial");

//adding x axis to the bottom of chart
 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height - margin.bottom)      + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.style("color", "#333333")
.style("font-family", "Arial");


//bar labels

  svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .selectAll(".textlabel")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .attr("class", "textlabel")
 .style("font-family", "Arial")
 .style("font-size", "15px")
 .attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d["Ward"]) + (xScale.rangeBand()/2); })
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d["Unemployment"]) - 3 ; })
 .text(function(d){ return (d["Unemployment"] + "%"); });

  // Y-axis labels
 svg.append("text")
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .style("font-size", "13px")
 .style("color", "#333333")
 .attr("transform", "translate ("+ (padding/4) + "," +(height/2)+")     rotate(-90)")
 .text("Unemployment")
 .style("font-family", "Arial"); 

// X-axis labels
 svg.append("text")
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "13px")
   .style("color", "#333333")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/2) + "," +(height-(padding/4)) + ")")
 .text("Ward")
 .style("font-family", "Arial"); 

 //title for the chart 

 svg.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("font-size", "16px")
.style("color", "#333333")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/3.78) + "," +(height/30) + ")")
.text("Unemployment by Ward")
.style("font-family", "Arial");

//source

svg.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("font-size", "13px")
.style("color", "#333333")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/3.2) + "," +(height/1) + ")")
.text("Source:Bureau of Labor Statistics")
.style("font-family", "Arial")

 })


 </script>
 </body>
 </html
```

The CSV used for this is:

```
Ward    Unemployment
1   4.5
2   4.3
3   4
4   5.7
5   7.9
6   5.2
7   11
8   14.2
```

I want to be able to change the code to select this part of the data set from a bigger csv which includes 56 rows and 6 columns. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the bigger CSV look like?  You only want to parse 8 rows (out of 56) and 2 columns (out of 6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the csv to create a subset of the data before passing it to d3.

At the top of your d3.csv call do something like

```
var newData = data.filter(filterCriteria);
```

And have a filterCriteria function that returns true or false based on what you want to show:

```
function filterCriteria(d) {
    return d.month === targetMonth;
}
```

Where `targetMonth` equals the month you want to show.

Then pass newData to d3.

Comment: How do we pass what month d should be? in other words if we want to select feb or mar, how do we pass that month to only show that specfic month.

Comment: For a static chart just set the target month in a variable: `var targetMonth = "feb"`. If you want to a viewer to be able to select different months and have the chart update you can change the variable based on user input and use d3 enter, update and exit to redraw the chart with the new month.